# Do I have to use x-tmpl in rails when using blueimp jQuery File Upload?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2, blueimp, jquery-templates, multiple-file-upload

I added `jQuery File Upload` to my `rails` app recently similar to what is shown under following link: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Rails-setup-for-V6 .

Every rails implementation version i saw till now has a `<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">`-part. Inside of these script tags is a template for listing existing data.

There is also a `<script id="template-download" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">` version at https://github.com/yortz/carrierwave_jquery_file_upload/blob/master/app/views/pictures/_template-download.html.erb which is very similar to `x-tmpl`.

My questions are:

What are the benefits of `x-tmpl`?

At [github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Template-Engine](http://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Template-Engine) is written:

> "However, you are not required to use this specific template engine
>   and can replace it with a different implementation, by setting the
>   uploadTemplateId, downloadTemplateId, uploadTemplate and
>   downloadTemplate Options" For me it sounds like its possible to use
>   normal `_partial_xy.html.erb` instead of x-tmpl.

Am i mistaken?

if yes, is it at least possible to use rails helpers inside the template like number_to_currency or do i have to implement it like it is done for formatFileSize in jquery.fileupload-ui.js?

Comment: for the code you are using you have to xtmpl only..